# PHP mysql How to split a string before a special character that lies before the end of the desired new substring?

Tags: php, utf-8, special-characters, json

Ive encountered a weird problem when outputting an array using `json_encode($string)`.

This problem arises if I call `$name = mb_substr($name, 0, 100);` and the last character (at $name[100]) happens to be a special character on a string that is written to the database and then outputted with `json_encode()` later.

I am encoding the string before hand with `$string1 = mysql_real_escape_string ( $string );` and then `$string1 = mb_convert_encoding($string1, "UTF-8", "auto");` to make sure the strings are UTF-8 (the DB charset is UTF-8 too). If I do this, I can store the new string in the database, SELECT it into an array, but `json_encode()` fails.

If I do not split the string to start with, everything works fine.

I have already tried encoding with `$response = array_map('utf8_encode', $response);`, `json_encode ( $response, true )` and `json_encode ( $response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE )`. However none of the above has worked.

So in essence my question is: How do get the substring of a string (from position 0 - 100) and ignoring a special character that may be split in half at the end of the string?

**An example string that I have split that cannot be JSON encoded**

```
ðŸ”¶âœ¨â‡ðŸ”³â—¼ðŸŒŸâ­ðŸ”²ðŸ”³ðŸ”³â¬…â¬…ðŸ•šðŸ•šâ¬‡â¬‡â¬â¬…ðŸ•”ðŸ•”ðŸ•“ðŸ•“ðŸ•
```

If anyone can help me out on this one I would be most grateful. 
Cheers.

Comment: If you would always use proper `utf-8` you won't have this problem. This is not a solution to you actual problem but I would advice you to use only `utf-8` everywhere and then you can skip this whole encoding and decoding stuff which often leads to strange behaviors.

Comment: I always do use utf-8 encoding and everything works fine, until I try to split a string on a special char. My other function calls in the OP are just there to "make sure" it is UTF-8

Comment: But if you always use `utf-8` you can be sure that the content you work with in PHP is always `utf-8` too. So you don't need to ensure that. Btw your string encodes fine using `json_encode()` and results in something like: `\u00f0\u0178\u201d\u00b6\u00e2\u0153\u00a8\u00e2...`. So what's the error message you get?

Comment: I'm not actually getting any sort of error in the error log, the json_encode just isnt printing anything. I can still echo around where it is called. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` at the beginning of your PHP file and `display_errors` set to `on` in the `PHP.ini` or `.htaccess` file? This should be done for every development environment.

Comment: Here is a paste bin of the whole array I am trying to return as a json_encode. 
http://pastebin.com/vvFrzDeV

The first text block containing the special characters is the one that is causing the encode to fail even though there is another section of special characters later (which encodes fine). The first one is the trimmed string I was reffering to earlier

Comment: I asked you if you turned on error reporting, not if you can send me a var_dump of your array.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I sent that to you as a bit more info, before I saw that you had replied. No I didnt have either of those values set, I have now set the `display_errors` and added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of my php file, still nothing in the error log. I have been getting other errors in the log already without having to set those values

Comment: With `display_errors` set to `on` they shoould appear on the screen instead of the log file. Well `json_encode()` can not fail silently. So somewhere has to be an error message and we need this to help you. So `json_decode()` returns `false` in your case?

Comment: Hmm, no even with error_reporting it does not print out anything. However if I remove the remnants of the "broken" character from the string in the database, (`ðŸ”¶âœ¨â‡ðŸ”³â—¼ðŸŒŸâ­ðŸ”²ðŸ”³ðŸ”³â¬…â¬…ðŸ•šðŸ•šâ¬‡â¬‡â¬â¬…ðŸ•”ðŸ•”ðŸ•“ðŸ•“`) the JSON encodes correctly. Is this a bug with the json_encode function as most of the other special characters are the same as the split-up end one? So to my mind, the solution to this problem is to find a way to find the substring without including a trailing half character, as even if the json_encode did print, it would leave some random unwanted characters

Comment: Update, here is an error when I call `json_last_error_msg()` `Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`